# Recode multiple variables on the fly in a html/php report

Tags: php

I'm working on a html report for users on my wordpress website taking watupro quizzes. By default watupro has a shortcode (%%-CATEGORY-POINTS-X%%) (where x refers to a specific set of questions), which when plugged on the report, will automatically give the total points for x-category. Since those points varies a lot by subscales, I would like to replace each of those value by a conditional statement. In the present case, when %%-CATEGORY-PONTS-X%% = 1, I would like to replace the 1 by A, a 2 by B, a 3 by C and so on.

My current attempt at integrating a php code did not go so well. Anyone know what I am missing in this code? Thank you

```
<?php
$management = '%%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%%';
switch ($management) {
case '1':
echo 'A';
break;
case '2':
echo 'B';
break;
case '3':
echo 'C';
break;
default:
echo 'D';
break;
}
?>
```

Edit: Sorry I didn't explain myself well. %%CATEGORY-POINTS-X%% could be interpreted as %%CATEGORY-POINTS-MANAGEMENT%%, which gives a value from 1 to 10 based on the number of points a user obtained for the management subscale. I have multiple subscales (leadership, empathy, etc.) and they each have their ID (from 1 to 10, and to call to them I replace the x value by the appropriate ID).

Comment: What is the max number of X in CATEGORY-PONTS-X?

Comment: This is pseudocode? `$management` is static so you will always get `D` if not. If you go beyond 26 what is the expected behavior, or 3 is the max?

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement seems to be wrong; Now confirm that I following your logic - Your `$management` variable `==` `%%-CATEGORY-POINTS-X%%` where `X` will `==` 1 through 3?

So i have to assume that you are getting `D` every time.

If that's the case; you have to use your cases with:

```
switch ($management)
{
    case '%%-CATEGORY-POINTS-1%%':
        echo 'A';
        break;
    // ... 
}
```

You have to check the whole value of the string; it's basically `if($management == 'VALUE')`.

Comment: It is not the -x value that changes but rather the whole %%CATEGORY-POINTS-X%% that becomes a value. The x represents my subscales, but for simplicity it could be interprated as %%CATEGORY-POINTS-MANAGEMENT%% where this code will give a value from 1 to 10 depending on the user score on the management scale.

Comment: Does the string match the `case` statement?

Comment: @Guillaume the string value shouldn't matter as long as the `case` matches the correct string.

Comment: but how to provide the condition?

For instance, when %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% = 1, display A; when %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% = 2, display B; when %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% = 3, display c

Comment: Just like you are currently doing... Just make sure the whole string is accounted for. You could use `if/else` clauses and use `strops()` which will check for the `needle` in the `haystack`. But you can also set questions and responses into array and map the array.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a short example for that? I tried every code offered on the page but I did not manage to make any of them work.

Comment: Yes, give me a minute

Comment: @Guillaume what are you getting back from the server? How do you actually receive the score for each section?

Comment: Directly in my wordpress dashboard, I have the Watu Pro plugin. People complete a test while being logged in, and I have a report made in html. Inside the report I use various shortcodes which are part of watupro. So for instance, ID 1 is associated with a management subscale, so simply writing %%category-points-1%% will give me a score between 1 and 18, depending on how many points a user accumulated for this specific subscale.

Comment: So what is `%%CATEGORY-POINTS-MANAGEMENT%%`?

Comment: It is only a variation of category-points-1. The x from the formula correspond to an ID, and each ID is linked with the name of a subscale. So category-points-1 and category-points-management refer to the same variable, which is the total points obtained by a test taker to the management subscale

Comment: @Guillaume can you please give me an example?

Comment: Well for instance at some point in my report I have this: 
<span style="font-family: Cambria;"> %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% </span>. I have numerous variations of points-x, as well as description-x and title-x. My HTML document is automatically sent to docraptor when a user complete a test, providing me with a personalized pdf with user-specific fields, which gives something close to this: https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/ec3bfc_ed5b4a4389d240a3a127999ae653122e.pdf

Now on the 4th page, instead of using numbers, I would like to use grades, by replacing 1 for a, 2 for b, 3 for c, etc.

Comment: @Guillaume what are the actual values you get back? I am not really understanding what the different between `%%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%%` and `%%CATEGORY-POINTS-MANAGEMENT%%` is. Are you receiving an array from the results? Or `$_POST` and their `key` value pairs?

Comment: %%category-points-1%% is exactly the same thing as %%category-points-management%% (%%category-points-2 is the same as category-points-leadership, category-points-3 is the same as category-points-composure, etc.)

I do not know how watupro was coded. If I make a certificate with only the variable %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% in it and nothing else, once I click on 'generate a PDF report', it will give a number between 1 and 18. This number is the total score of a user on a management subscale. However instead of a number from 1 to 18, I would like to show a letter, and the owner of watupro...

Comment: ...told  me to insert a php function in my certificate that would modify the value of %%category-points-1%% to another value using if else condition.

Comment: @Guillaume so why is the `switch` statement not working? What are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the max number of X in "CATEGORY-PONTS-X" is 26,

You could use [`preg_match()`](https://php.net/preg_match) to use a regular expression and extract the number in the string. Then, you could use the number to add to [`ord('A')`](https://php.net/ord) and [`chr()`](https://php.net/chr) to get the according letter:

```
$management = '%%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%%';
if (preg_match('~%%CATEGORY-POINTS-(\d+)%%~', $management, $matches)) {
    echo chr(ord('A') + ($matches[1]-1));
}
```

Will outputs:

```
A
```

The code inside the preg_match():

```
$value = 1;
echo chr(ord('A') + ($value - 1)); // A
$value = 2;
echo chr(ord('A') + ($value - 1)); // B
```

Comment: I explained myself wrong. It is not the x value that changes, but the full CATEGORY-POINTS-X. For instance,  when %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% = 1, display A; when %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% = 2, display B; when %%CATEGORY-POINTS-1%% = 3, display c, and so on. the x value simply refers to the ID of my test subscales (it could be interprated as category-points-management)

Comment: @Guillaume Oh. But how is converted `'%%CATEGORY-POINTS-X%%'` to `1` or `2`, ...? The code above (in preg_match()) could convert a value from 1 to 26 into 'A' to 'Z'.

Comment: It's a shortcode embeded in Watupro (the quiz software). I do not add code other than this shortcode to get the number of points a user obtained for a specific subscale.

Comment: @Guillaume What is the max value if the string ? I've updated the code (see last part).

Comment: The possible values are between 1 and 18

Comment: @Guillaume So, the last part of the answer should work :) Just replace `$value` by your result. It will avoid a multiple `switch()`..`case:`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so new at this, I have difficulty even adding the appropriate code at the right place. Is it possible to have a short overview of what it's all supposed to look like together? I tried a few variations when adding the code but I keep on getting nothing where it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The `switch-case` statement does only work on the `$management` variable in your case. Basically, the following two statements are equal:

```
switch ($var) {
    case '1':
        echo 'First!';
        break;
    case '2':
        echo 'Second!';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Whatever...';
        break;
}
```

and

```
if ($var === '1') {
    echo 'First!';
} else if ($var === '2') {
    echo 'Second!';
} else {
    echo 'Whatever...';
}
```

So you obviously cannot use `$management = '%%-CATEGORY-POINTS-1%%';` in your script, because then all comparisons fail.

What you want to do is use a regex, I guess. The following should do it for you:

```
$regex = '/^%%\-CATEGORY\-POINTS\-(.+)%%$/';
preg_match($regex, $management, $matches);

$set = $matches[1];
switch ($set) {
    // your old code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$shortcode = '%%-CATEGORY-POINTS-1%%';
$searcharray = array("1","2","3");
$replacementarray = array("A","B","C");
if(intVal(substr($shortcode,19,20))<=3){
  $shortcode = str_replace($searcharray, $replacementarray, $shortcode);
}else{
$shortcode = "%%-CATEGORY-POINTS-D%%';
}
?>
```